# HTML5 table styling without access to CSS file

Tags: html

I'm trying to recreate this table in HTML5. It doesn't have to look perfectly like this, just close enough. I don't have access to the CSS file. Grateful for any advice on best practice.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you use inline CSS?

Comment: maybe you mean: you have no access to external css file... but you can do it with inline style?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant I don't have access to the CSS file -- I can use inline style.

Comment: I don't have access to the page header. So basically I'm editing HTML from a rich text box which is part of a CMS. (I should've mentioned that) Whatever I do, it seems the CSS overrides the inline styles. Beyond that though, I didn't think the border attribute was supported in HTML5. See this from W3 schools: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_border

Comment: CSS border is fully supported, HTML table border is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Options you have:

Three options, from worst to best:

- Style all HTML `<table>` elements manually using inline styles such as

  ```
   <table style='width:80%;margin:auto;'>
  ```

  This is not at all recommended but will overwrite *almost* all CSS defined styles.
- Use a `<style>` tag to set styles in the header of your HTML file, which in effect is having an inline-CSS stylesheet within your HTML document.

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  <style>
  table tr th {
      color: orange;
      font-weight: bold;
  }
  </style>
  ```

  You should note that the `<style>` markup should come **after** the styles sheets have been defined (see example above) otherwise the external stylesheets will overwrite your `<style>` elements (because they're loaded after it).
- Use another style sheet for this specific table element. In order to minimise overwrite and maximise focus you can define the table with an `id` and your style sheet will simply use that id reference.

  HTML Body:

  ```
      <table id='mytable'>....</table>
  ```

  CSS Stylesheet file:

  ```
  #mytable tr td{
     background-color:#ccc;
     }
  etc. etc.
  ```

  HTML Head:

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="existingStyleSheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myTableStyle.css">
  ```

  As long as your own style sheet is applied last, (as exampled) after the current style sheets, it's rules will *usually* overwrite the already set inherited rules. More so if the styles are applied via an `id` reference (rather than a class).

***Recommended***: Make a new  Style sheet and attach it last to your HTML document.

Best practise is NOT to use inline styles and to use external style sheets uniformally, referencing elements as specifically as possible.

### Response to Question comments:

If you can't access the `<head>` of the HTML document then you have to use `style` inline tags. If these tag effects are being overwritten then you should check the exact rules that are over writing them, check for the `!important` marker and apply this same marker to your own inline CSS styles:

```
<table style='border: 1px solid #000 !important;'></table>
```

The above should not be able to be overwritten by anything, but other CSS rules can interfere, such as `!important` border declarations for `<tr>` or `<td>` elements can look like they're messing up the table border, etc.

[This may also be a very useful read for you](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `<style>` tag to write CSS inside your HTML, or use [inline CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)  (paragraph 'Inline Styles')

Comment: While these are both solutions, they are not recommended ones.